# Java ODBC Data Source ( undefined symbol: SQLAllocEnv )

Tags: java, mysql, odbc

I have the following Java code. Purpose of this code is to establish a connection 
to a remote MySQL database ProductionDb ( a data source defined in my /etc/odbc.ini file ).

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement s = null;
            String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";

            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:ProductionDb");

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

The /etc/odbc.ini file is:

```
$ cat /etc/odbc.ini
[ProductionDb]
Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so
Description = Production Database
Server = [ hidden ] 
Port = 3306
User = [ hidden ] 
Password = [ hidden ] 
Database = ProductionDb
```

By the way - I am using Java 7 and Ubuntu :

```
 $java -version
    java version "1.7.0_09"
    Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_09-b05)
    Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.5-b02, mixed mode)

 $lsb_release -a
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 11.04
    Release:    11.04
    Codename:   natty
```

When I try to run my program I get the following error:

```
$java Test
java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so: undefined symbol: SQLAllocEnv
```

Does anyone know why I get this error ?
What is wrong here ?

P.S By the way I did run sudo apt-get install unixodbc-dev , sudo apt-get install libmyodbc and sudo apt-get install libmysql-java :-)

**UPDATE:**

I have also tried the idea suggested in one of the replies below ( by Benny Hill ) : to use the /etc/odbcinst.ini as well as /etc/odbc.ini. Still doesn't work and I get the same error message.

```
$ cat /etc/odbc.ini
    [ProductionDb]
    Driver = MySQL Driver 
    Description = Production Database
    Server = [ hidden ] 
    Port = 3306
    User = [ hidden ] 
    Password = [ hidden ] 
    Database = ProductionDb

$ cat /etc/odbcinst.ini
    [MySQL Driver]
    Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so
```

**ADDITIONAL NOTE:**

I can use this ODBC data source successfully from the R
programming language.

```
> library(odbc)
> con = odbcConnect("ProductionDb") 
> con
RODBC Connection 1
Details:
  case=nochange
  DSN=ProductionDb
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using a MySQL JDBC driver?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at this to see if your JDBC/ODBC driver is trying to use the wrong .so file?

Comment: Not yet ..been busy ..hang on :-) peace and cheers !

Comment: Have to agree with @beny23 here ... Try using the MySQL JDBC driver ... http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like a missing or mismatched library. Try to debug the ldd processing.

First, check what

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so
```

says, do all listed dependencies exist?

Then, try setting LD_DEBUG and and start your Java program again, to see the loader debug.

```
$ export LD_DEBUG=all
$ java Test
```

Answer (score 6):

The error is the result of libJdbcOdbc.so looking for the function "SQLAllocEnv" in some other .so and not finding it. The way to debug this is to run the command **ldd /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so**. That will show you a list of linked .so objects and where they are located.

Generally speaking they should be in /usr/lib however if you have compiled any software yourself you may find that some of these libs are in /usr/local/lib or some other location. If you have anything that shows up in /usr/local/lib it's possible this is what's causing your problem. To test, rename the library in /usr/local/lib to something else (**sudo mv /usr/local/lib/mylib.so /usr/local/lib/mylib.so.SAVE**).

Now run your program and see if you still get the same error. If that fixes your problem then great! If not, let us know if you get the same error message or if you get a new one.

I would expect your odbc.ini file to look like this:

```
[primary]
Description             = primary
Driver                  = iSeries Access ODBC Driver
System                  = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
UserID                  = XXXXXXXXXX
Password                = XXXXXXXXXX
Naming                  = 0
DefaultLibraries        = QGPL
Database                = XXXXXXXXXX
ConnectionType          = 0
CommitMode              = 2
ExtendedDynamic         = 0
DefaultPkgLibrary       = QGPL
DefaultPackage          = A/DEFAULT(IBM),2,0,1,0,512
AllowDataCompression    = 1
LibraryView             = 0
AllowUnsupportedChar    = 0
ForceTranslation        = 0
Trace                   = 0
```

And your odbcinst.ini file to look like this:

```
[iSeries Access ODBC Driver]
Description     = iSeries Access for Linux ODBC Driver
Driver          = /usr/lib/libcwbodbc.so
Setup           = /usr/lib/libcwbodbcs.so
NOTE1           = If using unixODBC 2.2.11 or later and you want the 32 and 64-bit ODBC drivers to share DSN's,
NOTE2           = the following Driver64/Setup64 keywords will provide that support.
Driver64        = /usr/lib/lib64/libcwbodbc.so
Setup64         = /usr/lib/lib64/libcwbodbcs.so
Threading       = 2
DontDLClose     = 1
UsageCount      = 1
```

My example shows my setup for a remote iSeries but I'm sure you can see what you would need to change for MySQL.

Namely your odbc.ini "Driver = ..." line is wrong. It should be something like "Driver = mysql" and then you need to define [mysql] in your odbcinst.ini file.

Answer (score 3):

To fix this add the following to your startup script or profile:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:/usr/lib/libodbc.so:/usr/lib/libodbcinst.so
```

Your path may vary a bit, for me the .so files where in /usr/lib64.

"There is a bug due to the fact that the libraries "libodbc.so" and "libodbcinst.so" libJdbcOdbc.so are not loaded from the library that implements the JDBC-ODBC bridge."

According to https://code.google.com/p/queryconnector/source/browse/wiki/HowToInstall.wiki?spec=svn122&r=121

Answer (score 2):

I've used MySQL with JDBC before, and the easiest way I know to connect is using Connector/J which is the official MySQL driver. It will do the same as your ODBC driver, and doesn't require native stuff which may be causing your problem.

Get the driver from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Docs on above page.

Docs how to connect: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html#connector-j-examples-connection-drivermanager

Comment: @MarchingHome The asker gave the purpose of his question, and I've given a practical, experienced answer to achieve exactly same functionality. I know that people try to use ODBC drivers, when they could, and I think should (efficiency, JDBC-specific functionality), use official JDBC ones.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the directory:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/
```

And rename the file `libJdbcOdbc.so` to `libJdbcOdbcXXX.so`

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround and if SQLAllocEnv is defined in /usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so you could try to force loading it before using JDBC

```
 try {
        System.load("/usr/lib/odbc/libmyodbc.so");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

export LD_PRELOAD=$LD_PRELOAD:/usr/lib/libodbc.so:/usr/lib/libodbcinst.so

once I define this in .bash_profile, source it and it works fine for me.