# tomcat Starting Prroblem

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat6, maven-tomcat-plugin

when i start running my tomcat server, it throws this error:

```
error:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so: undefined symbol: SQLAllocEnv
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

[1]. May be this link solve your issue : ["undefined symbol: SQLAllocEnv" error in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21930727/undefined-symbol-sqlallocenv-error-in-java?lq=1) 
or this link : [Java ODBC Data Source ( undefined symbol: SQLAllocEnv )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979601/java-odbc-data-source-undefined-symbol-sqlallocenv)

[2]. If [1] dont solve your issue then please use jar of jdbc and try again
[3]. Share logs or stacktrace of errors for more information

Comment: logs are like this:INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/struts/tags-tiles is already defined
Jan 06, 2015 4:32:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://displaytag.sf.net/el is already defined
Jan 06, 2015 4:32:05 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://displaytag.sf.net is already defined
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so: undefined

Comment: when i am strating tomcatserver it encountered a problem like Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.

Comment: $ ldd /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/jre/lib/amd64/libJdbcOdbc.so
says, do all listed dependencies exist?

Then, try setting LD_DEBUG and and start your Java program again, to see the loader debug.

$ export LD_DEBUG=all
$ java Test i aleready test this possiblities but in my case not working